# How to run subdags with different time schedule interval?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have Airflow's DAG that consists of these tasks:

1. adding csv into staging table (t1)
2. delete old record from master table (t2)
3. add latest data into table (t3)

and one subdag that run everyday at the end of the day (11.59 PM or 23.59 24-hours format). The first three tasks must work first, then the subdags will run next

```
t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> subdag
```

The problem is, the first 3 tasks work well but not the subdag. I restart first than give error flag. I also cannot check where's and why it getting error.

I have try to redefine the `schedule_interval` from my subdag to follow expected result, from `12 * * * *`  to `59 12 * * *`. I also try from this blog post too  https://medium.com/handy-tech/airflow-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls-9ba53fba14eb:

This is the dag default_dag_args code:

```
DAG_NAME = 'order_bid'

...
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': start_date,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'project_id': models.Variable.get('XXXXXXXXXXX')
}
```

This is the sample of task declaration:

```
task_add_order_bid = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='add_order_bid',
    bql=order_bid.sql_itop_order_bid.format(
        table_order_bid_stg=table_order_bid_stg,
        date_from=date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        ),
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    destination_dataset_table=table_order_bid,
    dag=dag,

)
```

This is the subdag that I try to declare:

```
subdag_daily_bid = SubDagOperator(
    subdag=daily.dailyBidding(
        DAG_NAME,
        "daily_order_bid",
        start_date,
        dt_wib),
    task_id="daily_order_bid",
dag = dag)
```

But when I want to change the schedule, I declare my subdag like this:

```
def dailyBidding(parent_dag, child_dag, start_date, task_date):
    dag = models.DAG(
        '%s.%s' % (parent_dag, child_dag),
        schedule_interval='59 12 * * *',
        start_date=start_date
        )

    date_from = task_date - timedelta(days=1)

    task_del_taxi_order_bid_daily = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='del_daily_order_bid',
    bql=sql_del_partition_order_bid_daily.format(
        table_order_bid=table_order_bid_master,
        date_from=date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=subdag)

task_add_daily_order_bid = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='add_daily_order_bid',
    bql=daily.sql_add_daily.format(
        source = table_order_bid_master,
        yesterday = date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        monthly = a_month_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    destination_dataset_table=table_daily_order_bid,
    dag=subdag)


task_del_taxi_order_bid_daily >> task_add_daily_order_bid

    return dag
```

I expect my dag works at 12.59, but it still waiting to run and follow the schedule from the parents.

Comment: I wonder if  there's possible solution with use External Task Sensor, with condition if the current DateTime meet the exact time to run the tasks. But i dont have idea how to do it. But when it not meet the condition, i want to run a dummy task to wait until the time meet the condition

Answer (score 0):

According to this astronomer.io [post](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/subdags/), subdags must have the same schedule as their parent DAG.

In general, if you need to have part of your DAG run on a different schedule than another part there are a couple ways to approach that:

- You can use the [short circuit operator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator) to continue with the subdag only if the date stamp (e.g. `ds`) matches the frequency that you'd like. So your DAG could run daily, but only do the subdag step on Mondays
- You could break the subdag out into a totally different DAG, set that DAG to a weekly schedule and use a [sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.html) to check and wait for the data or just normal PythonOperator to check and fail if the data isn't there.

I have found with the second approach. If required data is not present, the failing message is a helpful signal to me that there's something bigger that's wrong.